# Should I create a separate repository for Unity Android

Tags: android, ios, git, unity-game-engine, gitlab

I want to know which is the best practice store iOS and Android in separate repositories or in one repo, Cause I have iOS repo and need to know should I create a different one for Android?

Comment: It is totally up to you. But make sure you don't mix them both. The iOS root folder and Android root folder should be siblings

Comment: I don't see any reason nor advantage in separating them. If you were to use the cloud build, you'd have to set different target repo(or even different project, not sure) so I'd say no, have it all on one place. If your scripts are properly written with macros, this will all go fine.